# PostgreSQL merge two schemas with identical tables

Tags: postgresql, schema

I've got some data from one year but it is split into two schema. How can I put them together in one schema so that I can process it with MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

If your table names in both schemas are unique you can use in the psql shell

```
ALTER TABLE old_schema.table_name SET SCHEMA new_Schema;
```

On the other hand I would be surprised when Matlab did not allow you to access any schema. Did you try to access your tables with `old_schema.table1` and `new_schema.table2`? In that case you wouldn't have to change the database.

**Edit**

If you have quite a handful tables, you have to issue the above command for each table. There is no way around this. But a little help: You can compute the commands and execute the results by hand. Computation is done with this:

```
select 'ALTER TABLE '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' SET SCHEMA new_schema' 
   from information_schema.tables 
   where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and table_schema = 'old_schema';
```

Comment: ok this works with one table but I got 28 and would like to do it by SQL code. Yes matlab can do that but I need one shema because  my GUI construction leads me no other choice.

Comment: hmm ok thx, is it also possible to merge two identical schema with identical table names?

Comment: No. You have to rename the tables first. `ALTER TABLE old RENAME TO new;` will do this.